# Opening another window from controller

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I have button named settings in my titanium alloy project. What i want is, to open the settings window upon clicking/tapping the button. So i have used following code

```
var settingsWindow = Alloy.createController('settings').getView();
settingsWindow.open();
```

In my settings.xml file which is my view has following code in it

```
<Alloy>
    <window id="settings">
        <label onClick="settingsAlert">Settings Page</label>
    </window>
</Alloy>
```

My problem is, i am getting this runtime error on my emulator saying

***Uncaught TypeError: Object# has no method 'createwindow'***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Alloy>
    <window id="settings">
        <label onClick="settingsAlert">Settings Page</label>
    </window>
</Alloy>
```

should be

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="settings">
        <Label onClick="settingsAlert">Settings Page</Label>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Alloy is case sensitive, `window` should be `Window` and `label` should be `Label`